# Tablekit: sortable not working if table rows are loaded with ajax

Tags: ajax, prototypejs

I saw this topic before here, but it didnt solve my problem.

I have a table that looks like this in html;

```
<table class="sortable resizable editable" id="tablekit-table-1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
            <th id="order_orders" class="sortfirstdesc sortcol sortdesc">Order</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tfoot>
    </tfoot>

    <tbody id="orders_content">
        <?php //data generated by ajax ?>
    </tbody>


</table>
```

On page load, the rows are loaded into tbody via ajax.

The problem is, tablekit's sorting doesn't work from there (only works if i output the rows from php).

I tried adding `setTimeout()` in ajax success, reinitialize the table with

```
TableKit.Sortable.init('tablekit-table-1')
```

etc, nothing helped. Googled alot aswell. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem. The solution I find out is using the `Tablekit.Sortable.init(id)` onSuccess.

But still I have another problem: it only worked on the first call, so I put a different id for every table I'm calling, and initializing the Sortable on this new ids.